# The union (and intersection) of a set, x.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading "The Joy of Sets" by Keith Devlin. In chapter 1, the author states:

"Suppose now that $x$ is the set of sets of objects. The *union* of $x$ is the set of all elements of all elements of $x$, and is denoted by $\bigcup x$. Thus

$\bigcup x$ = {$a|(\exists y\in x)(a \in y)$}

For the intersection, the author states that the intersection is the set of all objects that are elements or all elements of $x$, denoted by:

$\bigcap x$ = {$a|(\forall y\in x)(a \in y)$}

I am a little unsure if I am interpreting these two ideas correctly.

Suppose I have a set $x_1$ = {{a}, {b}, {a,c}, {c,d},{$\emptyset$}}, I think that:

$\bigcup x_1$ = {a, b, c, d, $\emptyset$}

$\bigcap x_1$ = {$\emptyset$}

For the union I think that a, b, c, d, and $\emptyset$ are all elements of *some* subset of $x_1$ (i.e., c: {$c|(\exists y\in x)(c \in y)$} where y is {a,c}, or {c,d}).

But, the intersection is *just* the empty set. Because, there is no common element among all of the elements of $x_1$. Whereas, if set $x_2$ were: $x_2$ = {{1,a}, {1,b}, {1,a,c}, {1,c,d},{1,$\emptyset$}} then the intersection would be $\bigcap x_2$ = {1} because 1 is an element of all of the sets of $x_2$.

Have I understood correctly? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Union is correct: all elements of elements of $x$. Intersection is wrongly written: $\emptyset \in \{ \emptyset \}$ but $\emptyset \notin \{ a \}$. So you have grasped the idea: the intersection is just the empty set, that means that $\bigcap x = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA, that is super helpful!

Comment: Yes, agree with Mauro. You will find that this concept is used a LOT in set theory!